# how to run several instances same role of the same jhipster war file with different config values

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I would like to run a war file on a amazon server several times, each time with slightly different properties like server port or database schema. Right now I have to rebuild for each case... I.e. how can I feed a spring-boot properties file at runtime to a jhipster generated war file?

Edited to clarify:

all I want is to be able to run two or more copies of the same war-file by specifying parameters (port, db name,...) at run time.
The instances are supposed to run on an Amazon system (Linux)
They are started at boot by a service script in /etc/init.d that also is used to start and stop in case of software mods/parameter changes.
As it stands now the application developed using JHipster only reads the file propagated thru the JHipster flow building with Maven (uses the -prod profile)
-Using a separate properties file does not work, it is not read
-Setting properties using -D results in the same: not read

Does anybody have any advise? It looks like JHipster has its own property reader...

Comment: Have you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-externalize-configuration ?

Comment: I did, tried it and it also did not work... I suspect that the setup with jhipster stops reading other files or -D settings

Comment: Please add details to your question like how do you start the app? Where do you store the external configuration relative to the jar and how is named the jar? Does it fail only in amazon or also locally? How do you set the active profile?

Comment: -the app is started via service script in /etc/init.d with a nohup or manual does not matter. It also fails under Windows with same error. I pass the external mods via -D's like -Dserver.port=9999. The profile is set by the maven build wrapper to prod (jhipster profile)

Comment: Please edit your question rather than commenting, it's a pain to read.

Answer (score 0):

To start the application on a different port, you should launch it with additional parameter:

```
--server.port=8081
```

or add parameters using `-D`:

```
-Dspring.datasource.url=whatever.you.want
```

or when you need multiple parameters:

```
-Dserver.port=10000 -Dspring.datasource.url=whatever.you.want
```

Comment: I tried this but the jvm does not pass the value to spring boot/jhipster as it complains of having no value for server.port. Tried with the url as well, same problem. Could it be jhipster reads only 1 file and no other info whetre via -D or in a supplementary file?

Comment: @EricVanHemelryck what about profiles? Btw, forget about JHipster - it's a great tool which you've used for generating cool application. Now it's just spring boot + angular :)

Comment: I used the jhipster provided profiles: dev and prod. So, in the war file I have a application-prod.yml file with a lot of properties in yaml format, but for the different instances some properties need to change. I have the impression that the .yml file alone is read...